# capturing groups doesn't work as expected issue

Tags: javascript

```
var content="xx<br>xxxx <br>@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy   yyy y ";
var rgx=/(.*(<br>))(.*<span class='black'><\/span>.*?\s)/gmi; 
var result = content.replace(rgx,"$3");
alert(result);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64vj5jwh/5/)

I need to get this -> "`@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy` " but instead, i get this -> "`@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy   yyy y`".Why?

And when i apply this regex -> `/(.*(<br>))(.*<span class='black'><\/span>.*?\s)/` this seems working as expected and [match this](https://regex101.com/r/rfbJLY/1) -> "`xx<br>xxxx <br>@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy` ".

As a result i wanna get only this "`@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy` ".

Comment: First you say you need `n>yyy ` and than you say you need `n>yyy` Those are not the same for one single space.

Comment: in this part "span>yyy ",  there is one space after "span>yyy" so -> "span>yyy<one space here>"

Comment: Sorry, but if you take a look at where you say: *`As a result i wanna get only this`* there's no space at the end. `@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy` so it's a bit contradictory

Comment: actually there is but not highlighted...i edited it and now highlighted.

Comment: Nope. It's not highlighted. Now you only have a space between the code portion ant the last doublequotes.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var txt = "xx<br>xxxx <br>@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy   yyy y ";
var res = (/<br>([^<]+<span class='black'><\/span>\S+\s)/gmi.exec(txt)||'')[1];
console.log(res); // "@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy " // or undefined if not found
```

To answer your *"Why I get `…yyy   yyy y` when using `….*?\s`"* - well, cause that's exactly what `.*?\s` does:
*get any character zero-or-more times including the last space*: "yyy   yyy y 
 "

Comment: 1)without using @

Comment: 2)any solution with only regex possible?

Comment: @lowdegeneration 1) fixed. 2) The above **does uses RegExp**. Learn more about [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: I run your code and i get "
xxxx <br>@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy " but i want to get "@yyy<span class='black'></span>yyy "

Comment: i realised you used @ but without using @ possible?

Comment: @lowdegeneration Yes, Tell me if the above should work now. It checks (and matches) that after `<br>` there's no other `<` , so any character that is not a `<` , one or more times - before encountering `<span...`